# Return MySQL by portion/ratios

Tags: mysql

This is not an easy one to explain so i will try my best

I have a list of questions in a database, and each question has a topic

I want to return 50 rows from the database... easy bit.

I want to return 50 rows from the database, but get a few questions from each topic, and i dont want to define an exact number from each topic, i just want it to grab what it can if they are available, as long as it grabs a few from each topic

Any ideas, clues, or the name of a MySQL function that can do this

My issue is i dont even know what to google to get what i want, is there a name for what i am trying to do.

Comment: `order by rand() limit 50`???

Comment: if a requirement is not clear to you first, if you cannot explain it in simple words, then you will probably fail to find a solution. Show sample data, show your desired results and your attempt

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a real pain to deal with in earlier versions of MySQL which do not support analytic functions.  With the advent of MySQL 8+ and the availability of `ROW_NUMBER`, the problem is fairly easy.  Consider the following table and query:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 1 AS topic, 'Q1' AS question UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Q2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Q3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Q4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Q5' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Q1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Q2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Q3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Q4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Q5'
)

SELECT topic, question
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY topic ORDER BY rand()) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

### Demo

The above query will return a max of 2 random records from each topic.  It uses `ROW_NUMBER`, but with a random ordering.  Topics having only one question would just return that single question.